# Making a class object belong to only one another class object

Tags: c++, class, object

I just want to know if it is possible to do something like this:

```
#include "graph.h"
Graph A, B;
Node n;

A.insertNode(n);
A.nodeExists(n); // returns true
B.nodeExists(n); // returns false
```

Since now I only stored a `boolean` var inside `Node` class, which tells me if a `Node` object has been inserted inside a `Graph`. But in this way, what happens:

```
A.nodeExists(n); // returns true
B.nodeExists(n); // returns true
```

which is incorrect. How can I solve this?

Comment: Seems like there's something wrong with your `Graph` class.  Can't really tell you more since you didn't post the code.  Use a debugger and step into the `nodeExists` call for the B graph and see why it is returning true.

Comment: This seems like a really-really ***bad idea.*** What's your **actual** goal you are trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: But 'Graph' is my implementation of a Graph class, which is declared in 'graph.h'. No need for a debugger, I just need to implement something which recognize the assigned 'Graph' object to a 'Node' object.

Comment: What is "graph.h" ?  perhaps you mean a boost library?

Comment: No, it's my implementation of a Graph ADT. I just need to design those two classes in order to return a correct value in nodeExists(n).

Comment: Your implementation of `Graph::nodeExists` is faulty. Fix it. If you do not know how, show us your implementation of the `Graph` class.

Comment: you can consider using pointers,because pointer is unique

Comment: " which tells me if a Node object has been inserted inside **a** Graph" - which means asking the *graph* whether a node exists in **this** graph should have nothing to do with that flag.

Comment: kiviak: yes, i did that, but compiler said "no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'Node<int>' and 'Node<int>')".

Comment: WhozCraig: yes, I know, but I don't know how to make a Node object belong **only to one** Graph object. That's the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Either you should store a pointer to the Graph object that the Node belongs to in the Node (thus replacing your bool by a Graph*). Then it's easy and fast to check has been assigned to a particular Graph object. Inside the Graph::nodeExists function just asK:

```
if (n.pOwnerGraph == this)
    return true;
```

As an alternative you could scan your entire graph and look for the the given node. That is much slower, but it doesn't require a Graph pointer in the node.